# Meteor Reactive Table onchange fields event

Tags: javascript, meteor, html-table, reactive

I couldn't find any question or answer about using a onchange event on Reactive Table.

I can console.log click events whenever I press any row on the table and log the values on that row.
But I'm having trouble logging whenever one of those field values changes. Probably I have an error in my syntax, I just can't figure it out and how to get it to work.

Here's my code:

tables.js

```
Template.tables.onCreated( function() {
   this.subscribe('adverts');
   var currentPage = new ReactiveVar(Session.get('current-page') || 0);
   this.currentPage = currentPage;
   this.autorun(function () {
      Session.set('current-page', currentPage.get());
      console.log(currentPage)
     });
   });

    Template.tables.helpers({
       table: function() {
            return Adverts.find().fetch();
        },
 })
    Template.tables.events({
    'onchange .reactive-table tbody tr': function () {
        var fields = this;
        Session.set('post', fields);
        console.log(fields)
      },
    })
```

tables.html

```
<template name="tables">
 <div>
    {{> reactiveTable showFilter=false showNavigation='never' collection=table}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` elements cannot trigger `change` events. You are looking for data changes not user interaction so a better way to handle this is to use observers:

```
var cursor = Adverts.find();
var handle = cursor.observe({
    changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument) {
        //handle change
    }
});
```

See the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe) for more information on observers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using observers solved my problem!
I did not knew that tr elements couldn't trigger change events.
Thanks again!